# PyTorch FFT2 and IFFT2 Results Vary Significantly from Matlab, NumPy, CuPy, and Original Image

Tags: pytorch, fft

I am working to compare several implementations of fft2 and ifft2 for use with images. I am comparing the results of Matlab, NumPy, CuPy, and PyTorch computing ffts and inverse ffts on a sample image at different sizes. The basics steps that each implementation takes are fft2 > fftshift > ifftshift > ifft2. The results of Matlab, NumPy, and CuPy are consistent with one another and the values from the original image once their absolute values are normalized.

The exception is PyTorch. When run on both the cpu and gpu, PyTorch produces differing results that are inconsistent with the other implementations, as well as with each other.

For reference, the sample image that is being used is the 'cameraman.tif' image available through the Matlab image processing toolkit. The image is read through skimage.io.imread() for use in the fft steps.

I am using:

```
Torch: 2.0.1+cu118
NVCC: 12.2
```

My approach to the fft in PyTorch is:

```py
import torch as tr
import numpy as np
from skimage.io import imread

img = imread('cameraman.tif')

imgabs = np.absolute(np.array(img))

# normalize the img array (for use in comparison)
imgabs = np.divide(imgabs, np.max(imgabs))

# PyTorch CPU fft
device_type = 'cpu'
device = tr.device(device_type)

imgData = tr.from_numpy(np.array(img)).to(device)

pytorch_cpu_result = np.absolute(fft_bench_PyTorch(imgData).detach().numpy())
pytorch_cpu_result = np.divide(pytorch_cpu_result, np.max(pytorch_cpu_result))

# PyTorch GPU fft
device_type = 'cuda'
device = tr.device(device_type)

imgData = tr.from_numpy(np.array(img)).to(device)

pytorch_gpu_result = np.absolute(fft_bench_PyTorch(imgData).detach().to('cpu').numpy())
pytorch_gpu_result = np.divide(pytorch_gpu_result, np.max(pytorch_gpu_result))
```

Where fft_bench_PyTorch is defined as:

```py
def fft_bench_PyTorch(img):
    for x in range(50):
        img = tr.fft.fft2(img)
        img = tr.fft.fftshift(img)
        img = tr.fft.ifftshift(img)
        img = tr.fft.ifft2(img)
    return img
```

Results are then compared with `np.testing.assert_almost_equal(imgabs, pytorch_cpu/gpu_result, decimal=6)`, and an rms analysis.

The results of my testing have shown that:

(1) Neither cpu nor gpu execution passes the np.testing assertion.

(2) The rms analysis of both results against imgabs are 8 to 10 orders of magnitude worse than the other implementations.

I am fairly new to PyTorch in general. Am I doing something wrong in loading in and extracting the img data from the devices? Is there something else I am missing? Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Is PyTorch using 32-bit floats vs the 64-bit floats of the other libraries?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That may be a contributing factor, but it still wouldn't explain why the results between the cpu and cuda execution are different in PyTorch.

Comment: Different implementation, different rounding errors. If they use 32-bit floats, compare them with a suitable error margin for 32-bit floats. Note also that all elements of the IFFT have a level of error related to the largest magnitude in the frequency domain.

Comment: You were right! I actually had to specify the tensors themselves a bit differently to fix it. Specifying them as "imgData = tr.tensor(np.array(img), dtype=tr.float64, device=device)" seems to have fixed the discrepancies between the floating point errors. Thanks for your help.